# Sound Devices USB pre / vs USB pre 2

Tags: gear, sound-devices, used-gear

I could get a USBpre very cheap. ($120)
Are the converters the same quality as the USBpre2?

Is it worth it, or should i save for the USBpre2 instead?

thanks,
John.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you're aware, USBpre1 does not work with 64bit operating systems - that's why you can get them cheap secondhand.